# How can I write a query that can list all the tables with a Specific datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write a query that can list all the tables with a specific datatype, it should list all the tables not the views, I have a script that lists all the tables with the specific datatype and also with all the views, how can I build something like this that can give me all the tables but not the views.

Current Query:-

```
SELECT
  s.name AS 'schema',
  ts.name AS TableName,
  c.name AS column_name,
  c.column_id,
  SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS DatatypeSchema,
  t.name AS Datatypename,
  t.is_user_defined,
  t.is_assembly_type,
  c.is_nullable,
  c.max_length,
  c.PRECISION,
  c.scale
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
  ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables ts
  ON ts.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
  ON s.schema_id = ts.schema_id
ORDER BY s.name, ts.name, c.column_id
```

Comment: Show us your current query!

Comment: Take a look at information_schema table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Query

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
       WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'--Give VIEW for Views
          AND EXISTS
          (
             SELECT
                1
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                    WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
                       AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
                       AND C.DATA_TYPE = 'INT'
          )
```

This will return All Tables with alteast one Interger  Column

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT       
       t.name AS 'Table_Name'
      ,c.name  AS 'Column_Name'
      ,I.DATA_TYPE
FROM  sys.columns c
JOIN  sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS I on I.COLUMN_NAME = c.name
Where I.Data_Type = 'INT'
```

The above includes columns but you could remove this.

The query works by looking at the `sys.columns`, `sys.tables` and `information_schema.columns`. Also by looking at these tables you can adjust the query to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on datatype, you could use.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where DATA_TYPE = 'INT'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select c.TABLE_CATALOG  ,c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME , c.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  c
Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    on c.TABLE_CATALOG =t.TABLE_CATALOG
    and  c.TABLE_SCHEMA =t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    and c.TABLE_NAME =t.TABLE_NAME
where t.TABLE_TYPE ='BASE TABLE'
and c.DATA_TYPE ='int'
```

**Note**:  int is data type .